# How to display two fields inline in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a forw, in which i need to display two field near each other: `select` + `input`. My code is:

```
<div role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter date" id="maps-filter-input-date">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="maps-filter-select-track">
        <select class="form-control" class="display-inline-block">
            <option>Select date</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter date">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="maps-filter-select-track">
        <select class="form-control">
            <option>Select date</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter date">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Looks it like this:

[image]

With black color is show where it should be. So is it possible to do with default bootstrap classes?

Comment: This is Bootstrap v2, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Bootstrap doc:

> Add .form-inline to your  for left-aligned and inline-block controls.

You will also need to set custom width to your form elements, see details [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<div class="form-group" id="maps-filter-select-track">
```

to

```
<div class="form-group form-inline" id="maps-filter-select-track">
```

here's bootply

http://www.bootply.com/e2BS204U7b

Comment: `.form-inline` is really meant as a wrapper for `.form-group` rather than being used together with `.form-group` on the same element.